# How can we pivot the query in the following way in the image

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I try to make pivot the table to the following image but i failed , the final result i need is as follow 
[image]

and the query i used is

```
SELECT COUNT(T.TTOutID) AS Currenct, TTOutTargetTrxnCount AS Targets, 
 B.BranchCode ,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order BY COUNT(T.TTOutID) DESC) AS RANK,
CAST((CAST (COUNT(T.TTOutID) AS DECIMAL)/CAST (TTOutTargetTrxnCount AS decimal))*100 AS decimal (4,2)) AS Percentages ,
TTOutTargetTrxnCount-COUNT(T.TTOutID) as Difference
FROM ALX_SalesTargets S
LEFT JOIN ALX_TTOut T ON S.BranchID=T.BranchID
LEFT JOIN ALX_Branches B ON S.BranchID=B.BranchID
Group BY S.TTOutTargetTrxnCount,B.BranchCode
```

and i make a tmp table for help

```
CREATE TABLE #Tempsample
(
    currenct int ,
    targets bigint,
    branchcode nvarchar(128),
    rank int,
    percentage decimal,
    difference int
);


INSERT INTO #Tempsample
  (currenct, targets,branchcode,rank,percentage,difference)
VALUES
  ('131', '2650','EXB', '1','4.94', '2519'),
  ('25', '3500','MHQ', '2','0.71', '3475'),
  ('3', '850','MNM', '3','0.35', '847')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `cross apply(values ...)` to unpivot your data, and conditional aggregation to re-pivot your data:

```
select 
    u.Attribute
  , EXB = max(case when branchcode = 'EXB' then value end)
  , MHQ = max(case when branchcode = 'MHQ' then value end)
  , MNM = max(case when branchcode = 'MNM' then value end)
  , Totals = sum(case when u.Attribute = 'rank' then null else value end)
from #tempsample t
  cross apply (values 
      ('currenct',currenct)
    , ('targets',targets)
    , ('difference',difference)
    , ('rank',rank)
    ) u (attribute,value)
group by u.Attribute
order by (case when u.Attribute='rank' then 1 else 0 end)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WLES86332

returns:

```
+------------+------+------+-----+--------+
| Attribute  | EXB  | MHQ  | MNM | Totals |
+------------+------+------+-----+--------+
| currenct   |  131 |   25 |   3 | 159    |
| difference | 2519 | 3475 | 847 | 6841   |
| targets    | 2650 | 3500 | 850 | 7000   |
| rank       |    1 |    2 |   3 | NULL   |
+------------+------+------+-----+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try pivot like this:

```
select 'Targets' as [Header], * from (
    select targets, branchcode from #Tempsample ) a
    pivot (sum(targets) for branchcode in ([EXB], [MHQ], [MNM])) p
union all 
select 'Current' as [Header],* from (
    select currenct, branchcode from #Tempsample ) a
    pivot (sum(currenct) for branchcode in ([EXB], [MHQ], [MNM])) p
union all
select 'Difference' as [Header], * from (
    select difference, branchcode from #Tempsample ) a
    pivot (sum(difference) for branchcode in ([EXB], [MHQ], [MNM])) p
union all
select 'Rank' as [Header], * from (
    select Rank, branchcode from #Tempsample ) a
    pivot (MAX(rank) for branchcode in ([EXB], [MHQ], [MNM])) p
```

Comment: it is good but , the branchcode is more than 20 added dynamically how can we do with this code. the length and the execution plan is more